# How to get users status from the discord API (URL)

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get status of a user without using any discord API language (eg. discord.py discord.js). The problem I'm having is getting a user from the discord API doesn't return the users status, how could I retrieve this information?

```py
import urllib.request as req

headers = {'Authorization': f"Bot " + "YOUR BOT TOKEN"}

with req.urlopen(req.Request("https://discord.com/api/users/<USER ID>", headers = headers )) as get:
    print(get.read())

# Now getting the user through a server
with req.urlopen(req.Request("https://discord.com/api/guilds/<GUILD ID>/members/<USER ID>", headers = headers)) as get:
    print(get.read())
```

Both when ran return users information like ID, name, etc. But don't include the user status which I'm trying to get

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: APIs usualy don't care of `User Agent` but I don't uinderstand why you use link in `User Agent` header - it is not correct method to send autorization.

Comment: There's no error. I've edited it to say that the API returns users information like ID, name, etc. which don't include the user status which I'm trying to get. But yeah the user agent is pointless. I used a url because it says in the API https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#user-agent-user-agent-example

Comment: what status? Did you check in documentation if Discord sends it ? Maybe it never sends it ? Or maybe it needs some special privilates for this?

Comment: As in user status (eg. online, offline...).
Because if I'm correct API languages use the same discord API. If so and they can get status then there must be a way to do it without them?

Comment: documentation for [GET guild memeber](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-member) shows that it gives [guild member](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object) but it doesn't have status like `online`, `offline`. Guild is not channel - you can't be online or offline on Guild - you can be online or offline on channel or on discord server.

Comment: "you can be online or offline on channel or on **discord server**" but the member in `/guild/members/<ID>` is brought from a server therefore meaning it should show the members stutas?

Comment: documentation doesn't show any function to get status - maybe it need different method or this information is restricted and you need special privilages or `discord` blocks this information for security reason (because spamers could use it to send spam)

Comment: module `discord.py` has [discord.Status](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Status) which it uses in [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) and you could check in its source code how it gets it. But it may be only your status - not other user's status.

Comment: You can get other users status too (solong as you're getting the user through a server) with the code like this `print(bot.get_guild(<SERVER ID>).get_member(<ANY MEMBER ID>).status)`. But yeah I did look into the `discord.Status` before asking the question but it's hella confusing

Comment: I dig in documentation and source code for `discordpy` and `discord.js` and I think it uses websocket for this - it would needs to create websocket and listening for event [presence update](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#presence-update) and wait for this event with current status for every user. I don't see method to do this only with `Request`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the gateway to get the users status as discord doesn't send them in the get member/user endpoints, you can see the event here https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#presence-update